# What are your favorite English language tools?

Tags: resources

To prevent myself from asking an obvious, silly question multiple times: What are the English language tools you found most useful?

I found [Corpus Concordance English](http://lextutor.ca/conc/eng/) extremely useful for looking up [collocations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation).

Please, one tool per answer.

Comment: **Mod note**: This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. Ordinarily, we would lock such a question; however, because allowing the answers to be edited and voted on greatly enhances its value, we have chosen not to do so. Please do not vote to reopen or delete this question; such actions will be reversed.

Comment: More organized list on meta: [List of general references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/list-of-general-references).

Comment: This chrome plugin is very useful. It's a good way to collect words. FlashRead : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flashread/ledjdgfkpniboodghppkjpifglndedoh

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't on Meta. Wasn't this on Meta?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would have a good home on Meta but is much too old to migrate it there.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox please take into account that other SE sites allowed one cw question to collect resources. This helps to disallow daily questions on resources. E.g: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese

Answer (score 39):

#### [The Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) (COCA)

This is a great tool for finding out how words are actually used in different registers of English, ranging from informal spoken English to formal academic written English. In [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-prepone-being-used-outside-india/843#843) I used it to find out if the word *prepone* was used with any regularity in American English (it is not). In [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/629/a-historic-or-an-historic/632#632), I used it to compare incidences of “an historic” with “a historic”, to see if one is used orders of magnitude more frequently than the other (almost four to one in favor of “a historic”).

It is also useful for researching collocates—which words frequently go with other words. For example, in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/757/correct-usage-of-on-at-and-in-from-a-foreigners-point-of-view/852#852) I used it to compare “on the bus” with “in the bus” (“in the bus” is used sometimes when the bus is stationary). In [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun/1428#1428) I used it the part-of-speech searching ability to compare how frequently *none* was used with a singular and plural verb forms (two to one in favor of plural).

Overall, COCA is a very useful tool for researching how the language is actually used, not only for debunking myths about language, but also for learning something new about how the language works.

Answer (score 36):

**[Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/)**

Language Log is a collaborative blog about language, most of whose contributors are academic linguists. It is one of the most popular blogs about linguistics, and there are often posts that directly address questions asked here. For example, there were a number of informative posts on singular *they* I linked to in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192/is-it-correct-to-use-their-instead-of-him-or-her/208#208), and [Mark Liberman’s post about the mythical rule forbidding beginning sentences with conjunctions](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002224.html) was informative in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593/why-is-it-bad-to-start-a-sentence-with-and/601#601) to the question “Why is it bad to start a sentence with *and*?”

Answer (score 34):

#### [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aMain_Page)

It's great for a lot more than just definitions. It's usually the first place I go for looking up etymology, pronunciation, and often derivations/cognates of words.

The cross-connectedness of information in Wiktionary is really what sets it apart and makes it an excellent (if sometimes imperfect) resource.

Answer (score 34):

**[The Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/) (OED)** is a very valuable and rich resource.

When you look up a word, for example, [favorite](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/68708), it provides a comprehensive account of use, history, synonyms, etc.

Note that unlike many free resources in this list, the OED requires a monthly or yearly subscription. However, [your library may subscribe](http://www.oed.com/public/access/public-library-access-from-home) and this would allow you to access the OED for free.

Answer (score 28):

**[Google Books NGram Viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/)**

Google Books NGram Viewer displays a graph showing how those phrases have occurred in a corpus of books over the selected years.

Answer (score 27):

**[Google](http://www.google.com/)**

Not Google Books, Language Tools, or even word trends. I mean the search engine. If I am curious about a sentence or spelling, I search for it. If the search returns interesting results similar to what I'm writing about, the sentence was good. If it returns badly-spelled pages about unrelated topics, the sentence is no good.

Answer (score 25):

**[The Merriam-Webster Dictionary of English Usage](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0877791325)**

This book, which can be [read for free using Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&printsec=frontcover), has a lot of useful usage information that is based on research into how words are actually used (as opposed to how some usage writer would like them to be used). Their commentary was helpful to me in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/495/less-vs-fewer/505#505) regarding *less* vs. *fewer*. It was also useful during my research for [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/you-and-yourself-me-and-myself/1186#1186) regarding usage of the word *myself* in non-reflexive contexts.

Answer (score 21):

#### [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/)

The British National Corpus (BNC) is a 100 million word collection of samples of written and spoken language from a wide range of sources, designed to represent a wide cross-section of current British English, both spoken and written.

Also searchable with a less elaborate interface [here](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/).

Answer (score 21):

**[OneLook Reverse Dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml)**

If you are looking for a word to express a given meaning, this is the place to go. For example, searching for ["soul guide afterlife"](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=revfp2&clue=soul+guide+afterlife) returns ["psychopomp"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopomp), and searching for ["fear long words"](http://www.onelook.com/?loc=revfp2&clue=fear+long+words) returns ["hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/what-is-the-story-behind-the-word-hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia).

Answer (score 21):

[**Etymonline**](http://www.etymonline.com/) is an online Etymological dictionary, very handy for tracing the origins of words.  Unfortunately it tends to be very terse, sometimes to the point of ambiguity.

Answer (score 20):

#### [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/)

This is a site for hearing pronunciations of words recorded by “ordinary” people. Many words have multiple recordings in different dialects, and each recording has votes on whether others think it is good or correct.

Answer (score 20):

[**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/)

An invaluable and up-to-date resource for looking up slang and other words that are often absent in conventional dictionaries.

Comment: Urban Dictionary can be quite valuable, especially in deciphering colloquial English, but I would like to mention 2 things: (1) I'm a native speaker of American English, and on occasion I've found it difficult to find an answer that makes a lot of sense. This is not surprising as English is highly colloquial, but I can only imagine how difficult it may be at times for non-native speakers. Also, I've seen excellent answers that have tons of downvotes—unlike the SE sites where you see the net score, this may confuse. (2) Urban Dictionary should be considered NSFW.

Answer (score 18):

[**Chicago Manual of Style**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chicago_Manual_of_Style) is really useful, especially looking at the example sentences of correctly-typeset English.

Comment: Only if you're being paid to follow it.

Answer (score 12):

Well, the companion to [**Dictionary.com**](http://dictionary.reference.com/) is [**Thesaurus.com**](http://thesaurus.com/).

Answer (score 12):

**[Fowler's Modern English Usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage)** (original book or the second edition edited by Sir Ernest Gowers) is fun to read and educational.

I don't recommend the new edition.

Comment: Easily my favorite book on my book shelf.

Comment: I've been reading the original edition; it's not only authoritative (for early 20th century),  Fowler pulls no punches; if it's wrong he clearly says so, and often colorfully.  Much very understated humour too.

Answer (score 12):

**[Word Net](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)**

It's a lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept. These "synsets" are interlinked. It's more rigorous than a normal Thesaurus, in that it tries to "pin down" every unique meaning of a word rather than just listing a bunch of synonyms with different shades of meaning.

It's a fascinating project. It's an attempt to be thorough and methodical about categorizing semantic meaning in English for use in computational linguistics and natural language processing.

Answer (score 11):

**[Practical English Usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_English_Usage)** by Michael Swan is very handy if you need to justify edits to a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 10):

[**Wordnik**](http://www.wordnik.com/)

> Wordnik.com is an online dictionary and language resource that provides dictionary and thesaurus content, some of it based on print dictionaries such as the Century Dictionary, the American Heritage Dictionary, WordNet, and GCIDE. Wordnik has collected a corpus of billions of words which it uses to display example sentences, allowing it to provide information on a much larger set of words than a typical dictionary.
>   <sub>[Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordnik)]</sub>

Comment: I am very happy that I found wordnik; I find it substantially more useful and easier to navigate than OED.

Answer (score 8):

**Google word translation**

The translation is displayed in a tooltip after you position the mouse pointer over a word. The [Google Toolbar](http://www.google.com/intl/en/toolbar/ff/index.html) includes this feature.

Answer (score 8):

I find [**WordWeb**](http://wordweb.info/free/) [invaluable](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2008/04/wordweb-my-desktop-english-teacher.html)

The software has a full dictionary and thesaurus for American, British, Canadian, Australian, Indian, and global English. It also provides synonyms, antonyms, related words, text & audio pronunciations for words you look up.

Answer (score 8):

[**TheFreeDictionary.com**](http://thefreedictionary.com) used with the print layout is currently the fastest online dictionary.

It is easy to [configure it to be your word search engine in Chrome & Opera](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2011/12/fastest-dictionary-on-web.html) so that you don't have to type the entire URL every time you want to search the meaning of a word or phrase.

Update: The dictionary service provided by Vocabulary.com is blazing fast too. It is easy to [configure the service to search for word meanings right from the Chrome address bar](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-search-for-word-meanings-right.html)

Answer (score 7):

[**Merriam-Webster Online, ask the editor**](http://www.youtube.com/user/MerriamWebsterOnline)

Answer (score 7):

Just

- [**OneLook.com**](http://www.onelook.com/)
- [**Dictionary.com**](http://dictionary.reference.com/)
- [**Acronymfinder.com**](http://www.acronymfinder.com/)

Comment: Looking for the meaning of a phrase or idiom?  **OneLook** will return the results from _several_ on-line dictionaries in just one search.  It's been an oft-visited website on my Favorites list for a long time.

Comment: **OneLook** also has handy [search features](http://www.onelook.com/about.shtml). For example you can search for words beginning with *ver* and containing *speech* in their definition by entering [`ver*:speech`](http://www.onelook.com/?w=ver*%3Aspeech).

Answer (score 6):

[**English Grammar in Use**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Grammar_In_Use) by Raymond Murphy is very nice for [ESL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_foreign_or_second_language).

Answer (score 6):

[**Project Gutenberg**](http://www.gutenberg.org) has tens of thousands of free ebooks. Useful for looking up old and classic texts.

Answer (score 5):

[**Phrases in English**](http://phrasesinenglish.org/)

This site allows searching of two- to eight-word phrases from the British National Corpus.

Answer (score 5):

[**Google Dictionary by Google**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja) is a Chrome browser extension that allows you to look up the definition of a word by just double-clicking it. (There is [a similar plugin for Firefox as well](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gtranslate/).)

After double-clicking any word you get a quick pop-up definition with an icon to hear the word pronounced. It also translates foreign words and supports the following dictionaries:

- Chinese, Simplified
- Chinese, Traditional
- Czech
- Dutch
- English
- French
- German
- Greek
- Italian
- Klingon
- Korean
- Latin
- Russian
- Spanish

Answer (score 5):

The [**Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/), from the publishers of the OED, is one of my favorite dictionaries.

It has entries written using the [Oxford 3000](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlist/english/oxford3000/) keywords, so they're easy to understand, suitable for learners and experts alike. Each entry includes British and American English audio and an IPA pronunciation key. The example sentences and [usage notes](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/usage_notes/) are great.

For focusing on American English, the [Oxford Advanced American Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/) is also now available, which includes essentially the same information and features as the American English parts of the OALD entries.

Answer (score 5):

This thread has some really good online resources.  It would be convenient if one could reference the bulk of them in just one place: a page of favorite links ~ an online wordsmithery of sorts.

[**The Wordsmithery**](http://tiny.cc/wsmithy)

Answer (score 4):

**[Acronym finder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/)**

A website that provides the definitions of acronyms.

Answer (score 4):

I have an old, well-worn, pocket-sized copy of ***Roget's Thesaurus*** on my desk at work (I'm a software engineer) that I find invaluable when writing documentation and emails.

Answer (score 4):

[**Google Books**](http://books.google.com/) is useful for searching for real usage and etymology of words and phrases, and for antecedents.

However, care must be taken with metadata, especially when only a snippet is shown: occasionally the book was published later than the the year Google claims it was, and sometimes they accidentally include multiple books for each record.

Therefore it's important to double check the date: scroll up to confirm the real date for "full view" books, and for preview/"snippet view" verify with another source (such as the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/details/texts) or [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/)).

Answer (score 3):

[**Chambers Dictionary**](http://chambers.co.uk/), famous for its humorous definitions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm an English as a Second/Foreign Language teacher, and I like to use the [**Cambridge Dictionaries Online**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/).

It has different levels of definitions from Learner's (which used to be basic or beginner) to Advanced Learner's.

I find it's not only helpful for me when I need to find a way to define a word for a student, but it also helps me understand words I may have never seen before or don't often use. 
They also have some mobile apps for English students, and a [blog](http://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/category/new-words/) that posts about new words in English like *lactivism* and lets you comment about them.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft Word's spelling checker**

But be careful with its grammar checker: it’s often wrong.

Comment: I don't know how many times this has saved me from writing "teh..."

Comment: Being from a field of science with specialized language, it is a challenge to use, even if I train it on my own computer

Comment: Be careful!  The grammar checker is a useful tool to spot slips, but do **not** treat it as an authority.

Answer (score 2):

**[Acrogen](http://ccsl.mae.cornell.edu/acrogen)**

An acronym generator generates acronyms from sets of words.

Answer (score 2):

The [**Internet Archive's Text Archive**](http://www.archive.org/details/texts) has old books and journals in many formats, including  plain text and scanned. Useful for confirming things only available as snippets in [Google Books](http://books.google.com).

Answer (score 2):

[The Economist's Style Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Economist-Style-Guide/dp/1846686067/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1335902331&sr=8-1).

Answer (score 2):

[manythings.org](http://www.manythings.org/vocabulary/) is an online "dictionary" which can help you memorize words which are listed according to their frequency.

Answer (score 1):

[**Word Dynamo**](http://dynamo.dictionary.com/)

Word Dynamo from Dictionary.com is a nice way to learn new vocabulary. It has flashcard sets of a variety of different topics.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Usenet**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) archive at [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/advanced_search?q=&) is useful for searching for Internet slang dating back to 1981.

Be careful as there's no way to search only Usenet, and some of the non-Usenet results are misdated, but it can sometimes be useful.

Comment: If you can't search 'only' Usenet, then how can you use it as a resource except through google, and then only if you're lucky enough to get results from Usenet?

Comment: @Mitch: Most of the older results are only Usenet, and you can tell from the summary page if the results are from `alt.fan.this` or `comp.that`.