# What is the story behind the word "hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia"?

Tags: etymology, neologisms

Was someone just trying to be funny by being ironic?

Comment: Is this real word? I tried googling this but there were several opinions (more like arguments).

Comment: I'm afraid that this is all monstrous nonsense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Sesquipedalian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sesquipedalian) means having many syllables, and you'll probably know what [phobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobia) means. Thus, "sesquipedaliophobia" is an irrational fear of words with many syllables. The prefixes "hippopoto-" and "monstro-", as you might guess, are not there to add anything in terms of meaning, in fact they are rather nonsensical. Their only purpose is to make the word longer, in a witty and cruel, sarcastic twist.

Wiktionary [says](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia):

> **Etymology**
>
> From *hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian*, an extension of *sesquipedalian* with *monstrum* "monster" and a truncated, misspelled form of *hippopotamus*, intended to exaggerate the length of the word itself and the idea of the size of the words being feared; combined with *phobia*.

So I guess the answer to your question is yes, you can say that someone was trying to be funny.

Answer (score 5):

It was an ironic way to say *the fear of long words* with a long word.

Comment: You should add more details to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

One of the earliest instance of either *hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia* or *sesquipedaliophobia* in a Google Books search is from Chris Aldrich, [*The Aldrich Dictionary of Phobias and Other Word Families*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A7iDw172KBcC&pg=PA234&dq=%22sesquipedaliophobia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2t4eC7p7LAhVK3mMKHXy4DrAQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%22sesquipedaliophobia%22&f=false) (2002), which lists both of them, in this entry:

> -PHOBIA: FEAR OR DISLIKE OF, OR AVERSION TO ...
>
> **sesquipedaliophobia** long words; also humorously hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia

However, a significantly earlier instance occurs in Dennis Coon, [*Introduction to Psychology: Exploration and Application*](https://books.google.com/books?id=K9ZXAAAAYAAJ&q=%22hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia%22&dq=%22hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiirPrn8J7LAhVU42MKHZyFD8Y4KBDoAQgbMAA), second edition [?] (1980), which includes this footnote:

> *Obviously by combining the appropriate root word with the word *phobia*, any number of unlikely fears can be named. Some are *acarophobia*, a fear of itching, *zemmiphobia*, fear of the great mole rat, *nictophobia*, fear of backing into doorknobs; *phobosophobia*, fear of fear; and *hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia*, fear of long words!

But that is as early as the entries get for either word. Two different reference works point out that *hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia* is one letter longer than *supercalifragilisticexpialadocious*, a nonce word that became famous from a song in the 1964 film *Mary Poppins*. It seems likely to me that the *hippopotomonstro*- prefix attached to the shorter word *sesquipedaliophobia* is there simply to make the resulting word longer than the *Mary Poppins* word.

It is difficult to find any mention of *hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia* that doesn't remark on the irony of the fact that the word for "fear of long words" is such a long word. But it appears to have no claim to existence outside the purposeful lengthening (for effect) of *sesquipedaliophobia*. Any word that appears on paper is a "real" word, in some sense. But I think it's fair to say that *hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia* is an artificially long word, not a naturally long one—and therefore that it did not come into existence under the same rules of formation that govern most words in the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Hippopotomonstrosesquipedalian, without the "phobia", appears in *Mrs. Byrne's Dictionary of Unusual, Obscure, and Preposterous Words*, by Josepha Heifez Byrne, published by University Books, in 1974.