# English tools for non-English-speaking people

Tags: learning, resources

Could you recommend your reference English tools useful to improve your English every day?

I constantly use:

- [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enit/test) for translations
- [Google](http://www.google.it/search?hl=en&as_q=%22do+you+like+it%3F%22&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&num=10&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images) with double quotes to test if my sentences are kinda correct
- [Howjsay](http://www.howjsay.com/) for English pronunciation

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools ?

Comment: @Ed Actually I see it as a different question. I don't think a native English speaker is going to use a translator for example :)

Answer (score 2):

Google Translate is what I use when I'm learning Chinese-It has romanization of the characters so I can understand it. For languages like English, it would be harder since it's unnecessary for such systems.

Checking on http://www.dictionary.com everyday for the word of the day, marking it down and looking up the definition could definitely help you improve your vocabulary. One every day would mean 365 words in a year.

Answer (score -1):

We recently launched a new website, www.english-attack.com, which helps people around the world improve their English via online entertainment. Multimedia exercises wrapped around movie and TV clips, news reports, visual dictionaries and games are combined with a videogame-like points and reward system and a global social network of learners of English. There is free content on the site, refreshed daily, and a premium content area.