# Examples of spoken phrases where the tone used changes the meaning

Tags: colloquialisms

I'm looking for examples of phrases & sentences whose meaning changes depending on the tone of voice used.

For example,

'Follow me.' (Said with a falling tone) would be understood as a command.

'Follow me?' (Said with a rising tone) would be understood as a question (ie. do you understand me?)

The longer and more grammatically correct the better!

Comment: Voting to close as "not constructive". Virtually *any* statement can be converted to a question using rising inflection.

Comment: Lists of examples are not good questions for his site.

Comment: @Mitch see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1431/11762) (one of the top voted on the site), and [this open question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2793/11762)

Comment: Although I must admit the first link there *does* have the "locked question" disclaimer.

Comment: @Jim: I was under the impression that, despite those two particular questions (which have come up in meta-discussions), list-like questions are not wanted here. I agree totally with FumbleFingers in that this one is particularly vaguely open-ended.

Comment: @Mitch I agree, but I think it could produce some interesting responses, so I'd like to give it a short time before closing.

Comment: My favorite: "These are the toys I have to play with." Depending on the way it's pronounced, it can mean the toys you must play with or the toys available for you to play with.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I like [that one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/pronunciation-of-have-in-i-dont-have-to-do-something) too *(Peter Shor's comment to PPL's answer).* Not least because you can't indicate that meaning change in writing just by italicising *have*. It hinges on the *have/haff* distinction.

Answer (score 5):

Practically all sentences have different meanings, or at least different intrepretations, when spoken with different stress and intonation patterns. Every native speaker realizes this.

Most [Garden Path sentences](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gardenpath.pdf), for instance, while disturbingly difficult to process in written form, pose no troubles at all in speech, because stress and intonation differentiates them effectively. Some examples:

- *The man who hunts ducks out on weekends*.
- *The dog that I had really loved bones.*

English orthography does not represent stress or intonation in any consistent way, and therefore has to resort to all kinds of artificial and ill-understood subterfuges, like [punctuation](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf), to try to represent at least a bit of it. The result is as you see.

Comment: And virtually any declarative statement can be made ironically, which reverses its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

*Won't you forget it?*

(normal question tone) *Are you sure you will remember?*

(angry tone, maybe kind-a question-y depending on the speaker) *Drop it!*

Comment: Negated or not, I expect most sentences starting with variants of *can, will, etc.* toggle between actual query and demand/put-down depending on intonation. Can we leave it at that. (? :)