# Commonly used sources

Tags: resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools)

I have a question regarding the English language that is too general for this site according to the faq. OTOH, I don't know where to look for the answer. Is there a list of sites, books, etc. that are commonly used to answer questions?

Comment: I can only propose [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites). Absolutely the best for answering questions.

Comment: Try asking meta for a list of sites, books, etc.