# Antonym of "extol"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What would be the perfect antonym for *extol*?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage! Your question has been closed because the answer to your question can be easily found by consulting free online resources—in this case, a thesaurus. If you do not know which resource to consult, please see our [list of community-recommended resources](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that list of resources. I'll try not to ask such direct questions in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Decry.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decry)

> **Verb**
>   **decry** (*third-person singular simple present decries, present participle decrying, simple past and past participle decried*)
>   1. (*transitive*) To denounce as harmful.
>   2. (*transitive*) To blame for ills.