# Looking for a grammar book

Tags: resources

Is there any English grammar book which describe how to talk/write English instead of understand English?

For example instead of detailing all situation where "would/will" is used, describing all different way to talk about past (or now, future, etc.)

Comment: Why this question has been considered off topic and closed?!

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq)--we don't want open-ended questions here. Further, your question isn't about the English language itself (usage) but rather a subjective question looking for a resource.

Comment: "we don't want open-ended questions here" totally arrogant and selfish statement! This question is completely answerable if there is any answer for it.

Comment: Is there one right answer? No, it's based on opinion.

Comment: What about http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools ? There is no single answer for most of question here because of the nature of topics. But there can be some nearly right answer for this question.

Comment: @johns-- its an old CW. Those questions are no longer in scope, and it's a poll--no right answer. I voted to close that one.

Comment: Any way I believe answer to this question may be just as subjective as answers to many other questions here.

Comment: There is an interesting & short & well organized grammar book called `<Grammar for English Language Teachers>`, it's very good & easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most comprehensive grammar book for foreign learners of English that I know of is the ['Cambridge Grammar of English'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521674395). If you follow the link to the Amazon site, you'll be able to look at the contents and some of the pages to see if it's what you want.

Comment: CGEL is *not* a grammar for learners. It is academic and theoretical and doesn't convey basic grammar ideas. CGEL is mainly concerned with finesses. How can a grammar of more than 2000 pages be a grammar for learners? The best grammars for non-native learners are not grammars by English authors but school grammars written by authors with the same language as the learner.

Comment: The 'Cambridge Grammar of English' is not the CGEL, as you will see if you follow the link.