# What is the word(s) for someone who is very particular about the small details of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for a word or multiple words to describe someone who is very (perhaps even 'overly') concerned about the fine details of something. It could be describing someone who is a perfectionist, or someone who is overly strict with obeying rules, or someone who wants everything to be 'prim and proper'. I recall knowing a couple of words with these connotations but they have completely slipped my mind.

Comment: Well, _now_ I can use a thesaurus, after looking at the suggestions in the answers. Its hard to use the thesaurus when you don't have a starting point in mind.

Comment: I agree with the OP.  Because of this question, at least four people stopped to think, and that is a beautiful thing.

Comment: Searching a reverse dictionary for ["someone who is very concerned about the fine details"](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=someone+who+is+very+concerned+about+the+fine+details) returns *punctilious*, *fastidious*, *meticulous*, and many more. There's your starting point right there. And it's on [our list of tools](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools), too. Besides, you can always just start with [thesaurus.com/browse/particular](http://thesaurus.com/browse/particular), which is right in the title of your question.

Comment: I was looking for terms encapsulating this very concept and found satisfying answers thanks to the question.  Yes, I tried a thesaurus, but as pointed out by the OP, they aren't easily utilized in this instance.  And I sure as hell did not know such a thing as a "reverse dictionary" existed, but I'm glad I know now.  In any event, I'm not convinced there was reasonable justification to close this, and, as I've implied, it seems to have been worthwhile since it helped this user.

Answer (score 30):

A [pedantic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pedantic) person gives too much attention to formal rules or small details.

A [meticulous](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/meticulous) person is very careful and pays great attention to every detail.

A [fastidious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/fastidious) person gives too much attention to small details and wants everything to be correct and perfect.

Comment: I'm mad at myself for not recalling 'meticulous'. Although i needed a stronger word than that, a thesaurus search for meticulous could have given me the others. God damned mental block.

Comment: +1 Also, there's one word for a pedantic person: pedant.

Answer (score 14):

[Persnickety](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persnickety)!

> a : fussy about small details
>
> *He lacked the patience to deal with such persnickety tasks as hanging wallpaper.*

Comment: Whoa, thats a good find. :)

Comment: As soon as I read your question title, it hit me in the head.  :)

Comment: *Persnickety* is just a quaint US colloquialism of the original *pernickety*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You make it seem that *pernickety* isn’t colloquial, but it is.  And ***p’ick’y*** is just the quaint polycontraction of either of them.

Comment: @tchrist: At the risk of seeming persnickety/pernickety/picky myself, I will simply point out that my newly-acquired OED lists *persnickety* as "*U.S. colloq.*", and says it derives from *pernickety*. The entry for the latter does **not** include the epithet "*colloq.*" OED doesn't have an entry for "*p'ick'y*", which I've never seen before, and would make no sense in speech - but the entry for "*picky*" defines this as "*Fastidious, finicky, ‘choosey’*" - obviously from "to pick/choose/select".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You must be looking at the OED2, not the OED3. The OED2 does not label *pernickety* as anything in particular, but the OED3 does certainly label it "*colloq.* (orig. *Sc*.).".  As for *p’ick’y*, I can only imagine how much your leg must be aching right now.

Comment: @tchrist: Consider me belatedly *contrafibulated*. I think my problem is I have too many other aches and pains to notice every new one when it pops up. But thanks for injecting a note of humour into my otherwise dreary life (even if it must be the slowest-acting instance of *"Laughter is the best medicine"* ever recorded! :)

Answer (score 10):

[nitpicker](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/nitpick?q=nitpicker) if you want the connotation of overly perfectionist

Comment: I think nitpicker has the correct emphasis on the "overly".

Answer (score 7):

The closest word I can think of is

> **punctilious**
>   *adjective*
>   showing great attention to detail or correct behavior: *he was punctilious in providing every amenity for his guests.*
>   <sub>*NOAD*</sub>

A punctilious person is one who lets no detail of a task or enterprise escape scrutiny and correction.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a noun, how about a *fussbudget*?

Comment: The association with 'fussy', that's certainly a handy word.

Answer (score 4):

Since you specifically ask for a noun rather than an adjective, I have these: fusspot, pedant, perfectionist and stickler.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose *pedant*. It's a person who is overly concerned with formal rules, excessively concerned with formalism and precision.

The adjective is *pedantic.*

Comment: Yes, that covers the 'rules abiding' thing.

Comment: The word *pedant* reminds me of that albatross charm pendant which my grade school English teacher always had danging from her neck as we read “The Rime of the Ancient Mariner”. And *pedantry* sound like the act of inappropriately hanging around with children, just as *pedagogy* is inappropriately oggling children. *Pedology* is studying the ground that children walk or ride bikes on. And *palaeopedology* is studying old farts.

Comment: You need to think about this word a little less :)

Answer (score 2):

picky

Comment: Did you know that you could use a random/nonexistent HTML tag to meet the minimum length requirements instead of writing these visible symbols? For example, `<aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>`. It will not be visible unless you format it as `code`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan What visible symbols? I used U+2060 `WORD JOINER`, which is defined to be a zero-width non-breaking space. Anything apart from a text editor in "show invisible characters mode" that shows you something for a code point which The Unicode Standard deliberately defines to be a zero-width space, and thus invisible, is buggy. A regular user agent should not be doing that? What are you using? This isn’t something from Microsoft again, is it?

Comment: I am using google chrome with default settings...

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan That’s peculiar, because Google is one of the most Unicode-savvy institutions I know. I’d  checked with both Opera and Safari, and didn’t see anything for U+2060, so used it. Hm.

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't display your U+2060 either. In any case, if it's not just in case of MY chrome, but chrome in general, you might want to consider using the trick I described in my initial comment.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan It's not showing up in my version of Google Chrome (v17.0.963.56 on Mac OS X Snow Leopard).

Comment: While the Unicode character U+2060 and its display characteristics might be an interesting topic, there are better forums to discuss it. The proper way to encode it in HTML is to use the `&nbsp;` HTML entity.

Comment: How about pedantic?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen someone offer the word [**anal** (or anal-retentive)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_retentiveness):

> The term anal-retentive (also anally retentive), commonly abbreviated to anal, is used conversationally to describe a person who pays such attention to detail that the obsession becomes an annoyance to others, potentially to the detriment of the anal-retentive person.

Comment: @tchrist It does on that Wikipedia link.

Comment: This term I had in mind, but it wasn't what I was looking for. For one thing, it is too colloquial for the article I was writing, and also it seems to me that the usage of this word is focused less on the importance of small details and more on the attitude of the person.

Comment: Anyone who says just "anal" in my hearing is always responded to with "wait, do you mean anal *expulsive* or anal *retentive*? " Assertively. In front of any company in any setting. Because I'm not the one mentioning anuses in that company in the first place. Calling someone "anal" is no better than calling him "rectal" or "vaginal".

Answer (score 2):

A Micro-Manager... I.E. My Boss

Comment: Not really a good answer, but I have to upvote for 'My Boss'.

Comment: Actually, it's a decent alternative, if the word is being used to describe someone in the work environment.  Merriam-Webster's defines the verb **micromanage** as _to manage especially with excessive control or attention to details_; Macmillan defines **micromanager** as _someone who wants to control every part of a business or system in a way that is not necessary or useful_.  Hyphen unneeded.  @TimLymington: don't we _all_ work for micromanagers?  Sure seems that way...