# What is the word or idiom for a person who pays attention to small and unimportant things?

Tags: adjectives

We were reading a text in my English class and One of my students Lost the line. I pointed to the line we were reading and instead of following the text she said teacher you have beautiful nails.
Now I am wondering if there’s an adjective, idiom or so which shows disapproval for

a person who pays attention to small and unimportant things ?

Comment: Would you like a word for someone that pays attention to trivial things *at the expense* of the important things?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what I’m looking for.

Comment: I think this is duplicate of this [thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109928/word-for-someone-who-pays-attention-to-details).

Comment: @Zico related, but not a duplicate. See my comment above.

Comment: Over concentration on details can be a symptom of a learning disability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word or term to describe when someone focuses on a specific example, rather than the problem at large?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222906/is-there-a-word-or-term-to-describe-when-someone-focuses-on-a-specific-example)

Comment: @Shorecoral - If you found any (one) of the answers helpful, please feel free to tick the gray checkmark next to the answer (it will turn green).

Answer (score 2):

We could say that she -

> **cannot see the forest for the trees**
>
> fail to grasp the main issue because of over-attention to details.

OR

> **has gone off on a tangent**
>
> to pursue a somewhat related or irrelevant course while neglecting the
>   main subject.

<sup><sup>**Source**- http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+off+on+a+tangent</sup></sup>

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One could be pedantic

One could be nitpicky.

One could be splitting hairs.

They have generally negative connotations.

Is it's a good thing then:

One could be paying attention to details.

One could be thorough.

One could be attentive.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you gave you might say she is [superficial](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/superficial?s=t). From Dictionary:

> 4.concerned with or comprehending only what is on the surface or
>   obvious: a superficial observer. 
>  5.shallow; not profound or thorough: a
>   superficial writer.