# A word that means “taking your time and doing things correctly”

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would describe someone who always goes out of their way to take their time and do a good job. Sort of the opposite of half-assing something.

I am looking for something that is more about a work ethic than a technically proper way of doing things. Something like **canonical** or **protocol** would not be a good fit.

Comment: What research have you done to find such a term?

Comment: Related: [_What is the word(s) for someone who is very particular about the small details of something?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59281/what-is-the-words-for-someone-who-is-very-particular-about-the-small-details-o)

Comment: @JohnClifford I have tried looking up words along the the same lines—including the ones I mentioned that aren't quite good matches—in a thesaurus or in just general searches. I came across this issue trying to name personal values, so I also checked lists of values for a match. Nothing has quite fit.

Comment: The closest match I can see from the related question Kyle posted was **meticulous**; would that do the job for you?

Comment: **Meticulous** is not a bad choice, but **methodical** submitted below seems to be a better fit to me.

Comment: "Craftsman" has a similar connotation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Methodical](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/methodical) - Dictionary Online gives

> 1. performed, disposed, or acting in a systematic way; systematic; orderly:
>
>    *a methodical person.*
> 2. painstaking, especially slow and careful; deliberate.

Comment: This seems to be the best fit for what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 36):

I'd suggest, ***diligent***

> quietly and steadily persevering especially in detail or exactness; *"a diligent (or patient) worker."*
>
> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diligent)

Comment: By far the best word suggested.

Comment: If you're a "diligent" work, does that really imply you're "taking your time with things"?

Answer (score 34):

[**Meticulous**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meticulous):

> Showing great attention to detail; very careful and precise

Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meticulous)

Comment: Your word is apt, but please add a reference (look at other answers to this question as a model), or your answer may be deleted.

Comment: In addition, since your definition is actually lifted from a reference verbatim, you absolutely *must* identify it as such. Mods are instructed to delete unattributed content *on sight, with no prior warning*.

Comment: I would, personally, say that this word is the best fit, although the other suggestions are suitable as well.

Answer (score 29):

I might also consider ***conscientious***

Defined by [Collins<sup>1</sup>](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscientious) as:

> 1. involving or taking great care; painstaking; diligent

[Random House<sup>2</sup>](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conscientious) says:

> 2. governed by or done according to conscience; scrupulous: *a conscientious judge.*

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2011, 2014</sup></sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub><sup>Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 23):

#### [Thorough](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thorough)

> ***adjective***
>
> 1. executed without negligence or omissions: a thorough search.
> 2. complete; perfect; utter: thorough enjoyment.
> 3. extremely attentive to accuracy and detail; painstaking: a thorough worker; a thorough analysis.
> 4. having full command or mastery of an art, talent, etc.: a thorough actress.

Comment: I don't believe this implies "taking your time doing it".

Comment: @einpoklum it does seem to imply taking as much time _as necessary_ to get it completely right. It may not imply doing it particularly slowly as some of the other suggestions may, but that wasn't really asked.

Comment: I can imagine someone being both quick and thorough...

Comment: @einpoklum Jusy as we can imagine someone being _"quick and methodical"_, _"quick and diligent"_ and so on. Even if _"quick"_ would be a possibly rare trait combined in these pairs, _"quick"_ does in no way exclude these other words. Note that most answers here focus on OP:s request of a word that is _"the opposite of half-assing something"_. Also, to _"take their time and do a good job"_ does hold some ambiguity w.r.t. referring to spending intended amounts of the entity of _time_, or simply _applying sufficient time and effort to the task to ensure a "good job"_; I choose the latter.

Comment: But you can't really imagine someone being both meticulous and quick; or at least, less so. Or punctilious and quick. At least that's how I feel. Anyway, "taking their time" does not mean the time is sufficient, less than sufficient or more than sufficient to get the job done - it just means done without any haste or rush, or even at a slow pace,

Answer (score 12):

Painstaking or fastidious, perhaps? Both words can be used as adjectives describing a careful tendency.

Painstaking: taking or characterized by taking, pains or trouble; expending or showing diligent care and effort; careful

Fastidious: characterized by excessive care or delicacy (some definitions include an element of 'demanding')

From [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/painstaking)

Answer (score 11):

**Scrupulous**

> having moral integrity :  acting in strict regard for what is
>   considered right or proper

"Scrupulous." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 12 Mar. 2016.

**Punctilious**

> marked by or concerned about precise accordance with the details of
>   codes or conventions

"Punctilious." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 12 Mar. 2016.

Answer (score 5):

A person who is **disciplined** not only has the patience to do a job properly, but makes the effort to complete all of the steps in the job.

A person who finishes a task in a **systematic** way is more likely to plan for the required amount of time needed for each step than someone who finishes a task without planning, and is also less likely to miss a step.

The word **stepwise** means to take an action in a series of steps.  This series of steps is a plan in and of itself.  Therefore, this word also means following a plan that was created to either properly complete a task, or to at least make a measurable amount of progress towards a task.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [perfectionist](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/perfectionist) would fit.

Comment: I just found you rolled my edit back. Was there any reason to do that?

Comment: @Rathony: If the answer is a not uncommon word, I don't see the need to spoonfeed readers. A link *or* a reference is reasonable, but not both, at least in my answers.  In yours, of course, you can do as you please. (Since a downvote happened immediately after the rollback, I assumed it came from you. Was I mistaken?)

Answer (score 2):

All of the given answers are good words to express the concept, but there is one more which came straight to mind when I read the question:

> Fastidious

Defined in the [online dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fastidious?s=b) as:

> 1.
>   excessively particular, critical, or demanding; hard to please:
>   a fastidious eater.
>
> 2.
>   requiring or characterized by excessive care or delicacy; painstaking.

The second definition is the relevant one. It's a very formal word for the definition required but may be worth considering.

EDIT: Sorry, @JesseM - I must have somehow missed your answer when I first read this question. I apologise for duplicating your entirely correct response.

Answer (score 0):

A word that has not yet been mentioned is [persnickety](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persnickety), referring to a person or a task as requiring great attention to detail.

It may have a positive or a negative connotation, depending on the context. For an example of the former, you can see advertisements for Tilley Hats, in which they refer to the onshore manufacturing with "[Canadian persnicketiness](http://www.treehugger.com/sustainable-fashion/tilley-endurables-a-hemp-hats-made-with-persnicketiness.html)".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will fit

> productive

**Example**

> He's a very productive person. There's no minute he would hang around.