# English equivalent for the Persian idiom "Putting the drill on poppy"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

There is an old saying in Persian that describes a situation in which:

- Someone is going into too much (unnecessary) detail while doing something.
- Someone does something with too much (unnecessary) obsession.

The literal translation of the saying is:

> **Putting the drill on [poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy).**

I should add, this idiom is used in a negative manner. That means if you use this idiom for a situation, then you're probably annoyed by it. For example if you say: **John is putting the drill on poppy**, it could never be a compliment,  you mean it as a negative thing (because it's too much) and you're annoyed by it.

For instance,
suppose your car has just been crashed and you're running low on money. So you go to the auto repair shop and you ask the mechanic to fix your car but you don't want him to go into too much detail; You want him to fix your car with minimal cost. Here is the conversation:

> **Mechanic**: Do you want to repair your car?
>
> **You**: Yes, but please don't **put the drill on poppy**.

I tried searching about the origin of this old idiom and why they used drill and [poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy) plant in it but couldn't find any useful information. I asked a few of my older friends and they didn't know either. I'm still looking for an explanation but I suspect it has something to do with harvesting [poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy) plant and maybe the amount of detail it takes to extract seeds from it (maybe with an instrument like drill).

Is there any equivalent English idiom/expression to imply this meaning?

### **Update:**

In case the words in the literal translation are not clear, I'm going to add what they're referring to here:

- **Drill** is referring to a tool with a rotating cutting tip, used for making holes. *(From google translate)*
- [**Poppy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppy) is referring to a herbaceous plant with showy flowers, milky sap, and rounded seed capsules. Many poppies contain alkaloids and are a source of drugs such as morphine and codeine. *(From google translate)*

Comment: How interesting. What is the origin of the expression? Why drill? Why poppy?

Comment: @WS2, I tried searching about it earlier and couldn't find any useful information in Persian sites. I asked few of my older friends and they didn't know either. I'm still looking for an answer but I suspect it has something to do with harvesting poppy plant and maybe the amount of detail it takes to extract seeds from it (maybe with an instrument like drill). I'm not sure.

Comment: "Gilding the lily" is an old metaphor, but still good.  However, it doesn't quite fit the car repair scenario.

Comment: If you're harvesting opium from a poppy, you slit the bulb with a razor. The paste drips out slowly. Now imagine using a power drill instead...

Comment: I chanced upon the phrase "using a sledgehammer to crack a nut", but I have no idea how much of an idiom that is.

Comment: @Sobhan, I suspect that 'drill' might better refer to the idea of the seed drill (still in common use) and planting.  Poppies self-seed easily.  Working a seed drill to plant poppies is useless work. In you original sentence John is wasting his time.

Comment: Maybe the meaning is "don't try cracking poppy seeds open, they're already very small"? Because this "putting a drill on poppy" looks just like a mix of words without any meaning to me.

Comment: @CopperKettle, as mentioned in the question, that is the exact literal translation. Word by word. So as a whole, it should probably mean something to the poppy harvesters. What Icy said in the comments could be true. If I find out any explanation, I will update the question.

Comment: The word "drill" has several meanings (see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/drill). Also, In English "poppy" could mean the whole plant, the flower, the seed-pod, or the individual seeds. So as a native English speaker, it's hard to guess what your "exact literal translation" actually means.

Comment: @alephzero, I've updated the question to reflect that. As for the **poppy**, my bet is that it refers to the whole plant. I'm not sure of this because the origins of the idiom is currently unknown to me. I've also provided the meaning of the idiom and the situation it is used at the beginning of the question. So literal words and their meaning should not be an issue.

Comment: Related but not the same "make a mountain out of a molehill"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In (British) English, a painlessly idiomatic usage would be

> Mechanic: Do you want to repair your car?
>
> You: Yes, but please **don’t go overboard**.

As thefreedictionary points out, ‘go overboard’ *literally* means falling out of a boat, but idiomatically one can also ***go overboard*** on a task:  ‘[to do too much; to be extravagant](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+overboard)’.

That can mean a range of things, from taking a task in general more seriously than it could possibly merit, to polishing thousands of tiny details that no-one could possibly ever see.

In the case of your example, the *not going overboard* scenario would involve the mechanic simply fixing the essential problem efficiently, and stopping there.

John’s colleagues would understand each other perfectly if one of them were simply to say, ‘John is going overboard again.’  They might or might not try to stop him, but they would understand that John is expending *unnecessary time and effort*, as usual.

Comment: Thank you @Captain, can you say this as a positive thing? For example if you say **"John goes oveboard on his job."**, is that a compliment? Because the idiom in the question is only used in a negative situation.

Comment: 'Going overboard' would never be a compliment.  It _always_ means unnecessarily _overdoing_ things, but it _could_ still be understanding.  If you say that 'John goes overboard on his job,' it might be a straightforward criticism, or it could be you kind of sighing, shrugging and giving up, knowing that John just does things like that, and there is no stopping him.

Comment: @Sobhan: The positive version would be *to go above and beyond*, as in, "John always goes above and beyond in his job." meaning that John is an extremely diligent worker who doesn't just do the minimum necessary work or even the normal necessary work, he goes further (in a positive way). If your mechanic fixed the car, but also gave it a thorough wash and polish **without** expecting any extra payment or tip for it, that would be an example of going above and beyond. (This is frequently paired with "the call of duty," e.g., "To go above and beyond the call of duty.")

Comment: It would appear from examples given in the OED that *to go overboard* originates from the game of pontoon(blackjack). *Going overboard* was jargon for *going bust* i.e. going above 21. In other words be careful not to go too far, and *go overboard*.

Comment: @WS2 Splendid!  Somehow I had become convinced, long ago, that it really was a simple overextension of falling off a boat (a bit like the British 'fill your boots', the US 'knock yourself out', or the Australian 'go for your life').  The pontoon connection is sort of undramatic, but also cheerfully subtle.

Answer (score 5):

There is the idiom [to take a sledgehammer to crack a nut](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-sledgehammer-to-crack-a-nut); it seems more directly related than some to your original.

Answer (score 5):

You are not understanding this saying in the target language. It really means to nitpick. It means poppy seed not the plant. The Farsi is مته به خشخاش نگذار.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [***split hairs***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/split+hairs):

> to argue about whether details that are not important are exactly correct
>   *- 'She earns three time what I earn.'
>
>   - 'Actually, it's more like two and a half.'
>
>   - 'Oh stop splitting hairs!'*

There's also the verb [***quibble***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quibble), but it's not figurative.:

> to argue or complain about small, unimportant things

---

<sub>Please note that the literal translation of *split hairs* works as an idiom in Farsi too, but it doesn't mean the same thing as the English idiom. In Farsi *split hairs* means something like *have a discerning razor-sharp mind*, and shows approval.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

*Don't **fuss over it***

> fuss over
>
> To handle or deal with something or someone in an overly attentive or nervous way: *Don't fuss over every detail—just get the main idea across for now.* *The grandparents fussed over their new grandchild.*
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fuss+over)

***Don't get carried away***

> *Fig.* to be overcome by emotion or enthusiasm (in one's thinking or actions). *Calm down, Jane. Don't get carried away.* *Here, Bill. Take this money and go to the candy store, but don't get carried away.*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+carried+away)
>
> *I think 'getting carried away' tends to have the connotation that one has worked on something so hard or so long that it has become much more than was originally envisioned.* [WordReference Forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/go-overboard-vs-be-carried-away.1605893/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't [make a meal of the issue](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/make-a-meal-out-of-sth)

Answer (score -4):

This has been addressed in [this previous thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59281), in which the expression I am leaning towards is "anal-retentive". If something more poetic is desired, one uses "misses the forest for the trees".

Comment: Jack, the idiom mentioned in this question is only used in a negative situation. That means you can't use it as a compliment or a positive thing in any circumstances. That is different than the question you linked in my opinion.

Comment: "Missing the forest for the trees" seems entirely unrelated.