# Nuances/shades-of-meaning online?

Tags: resources

Is there an online reference resource devoted to commentary on the finer points of usage, connotation, and word choice in English?

(E.g. what nuances/shades-of-meaning/usage considerations would inform the choice between "firmament", "(the) heavens" and "(the) heaven"? or between "spry" and "lively"? etc. etc.  I'm thinking of something in the spirit of the usage notes sprinkled—sparingly, unfortunately—throughout the M-W's Collegiate, but more extensive and up-to-date.)

Comment: See the helpful answers to the question [What are your favorite English language tools?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools)

Comment: Do dictionaries not suffice for you?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/lively) for such research. Each entry has, on the right of the page, a list of sample uses gleaned from the web.  At the bottom, it lists synonyms, hyponyms, and reverse dictionary entries.  The body of the page lists definitions from several different dictionaries.  I think you'll bookmark it rather quickly.

P.S. Before asking more questions like this in the future, you might want to read through [THIS](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools).