# Good online thesaurus?

Tags: resources, online-resources

Does anyone know of a good online thesaurus? I've used http://thesaurus.com/ and http://www.merriam-webster.com/.  Especially something that's good with phrases, figures of speech or idioms.

Comment: Try with Wordnik

Comment: Such questions are deemed not constructive. Please read the [faq] for more information. We have an [old question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) about resources already, so that should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out few informative resources on thesaurus:

1. [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/english-thesaurus)
2. [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com):
3. [Babylon thesaurus](http://thesaurus.babylon.com):
4. [Thesaurus on Yahoo Education](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/thesaurus):
5. [Thesaurus.net](http://www.thesaurus.net/)
6. [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/)     (suggested by Carlo_R)

**Visual Thesaurus**:

It is one of amazing things. You can check the words synonyms, meanings in the form of web links.
http://www.visualthesaurus.com/

Comment: powerthesaurus.org/