# Is there a software that can help my speech and grammar

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, pronunciation

Is there a software that can help me to improve my speech and grammar?...like learning the past participle,present participle and etc...also in constructing the sentences...or if there is no software can you tell me where i can start in learning my english skills.I know this is ridiculous question but i am serious to gain knowledge.I hope some one can help me on this.

Comment: Your question has been frequently asked on ELU, and ordinarily closed as off-topic.  However, you might see [What are your favorite English language tools?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools).  Also see [english-language-learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) proposal.  What's your native language, and how have you learned English so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are a non-native speaker, you might want to consider checking out the higher levels of Rosetta Stone for English. Obviously, you are able to speak English so the first two or three levels would be useless to you, but the higher levels, especially the fifth level, deal with perfecting grammar as well as expanding vocabulary. I have heard stories about immigrants to America speaking perfect English with perfect accents because they used that software.

Other than that, you may want to consider writing an essay, a long one, about anything that interests you, then have someone that you know is good with grammar correct it. Then, you can see where you make grammar mistakes and you will be able to avoid them in the future.

A final option is to take a community college class in English. There are plenty of classes that focus on perfecting grammar and improving speaking, writing, and reading ability.

Comment: Is Rosetta Stone for English is a software?

Comment: Yup, there are even American (http://www.rosettastone.com/learn-english) and British varieties (http://www.rosettastone.com/learn-english-british).