# online free dictionary of choice?

Tags: dictionaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools)

This may seem like a meta question but I feel it is really about English Language and Usage.

What is the preferred online free dictionary of this community? There are so many out there? Some internet based seems to be very advertising oriented while some other only seem to aggregate crowdsourced content from other sites.

Comment: There was a question called "What are your favorite English language tools?" that listed some online resources, but it was closed about a month ago

Comment: I must say that I don't remember *why* it was closed (the box says I did it). There must have been a discussion preceding the closure, but I am having a blackout. Either way, I'm reopening this question here to at least close it as a dupe of that question instead. It has a number of dictionaries voted on by the community so it actually answers your question about the community's preferences.

Comment: Got some downvotes but got an answer too; I am happy camper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questionable dictionaries, in print as well as online. If you use dictionaries a lot, it is worth paying for a decent one.

Online free ones... try:

[Longmans](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/)

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/)

[Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

Comment: Thanks! I did not want to suggest I don't like to pay for dictionaries, have bought them in past and will buy in future too.