# A word for "modify/delete/change a newspaper article"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary

a word for " a person/politician asking to review/modify a newspaper article before it is published"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some terms like  *quote approval,  veto power,* and *green light* appear in a recent [Guardian article](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2012/jul/18/quote-approval-us-news-media-rethink) on the subject of right-of-review.

*Quote approval* also appears in a recent [CNN article](http://www.cnn.com/2012/07/19/opinion/rather-quote-approval-reporting/index.html), along with terms like  *on background* (where interviewee insists on no quotes), *Faustian bargain* (as Dan Rather calls pre-publication-review agreements), and *lapdogs* (his term for journalists who agree to such provisions).  I suppose that if you agree with the second term, you could call the  person or politician asking to review or modify a newspaper article before publication  Faust.

The verb *[redact](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redact#Verb)* (“To censor...”,  “To black out text...”), mentioned in comment below, leads to nouns  *[redaction](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redaction#Noun)* (“The change or changes made while editing”, “The process of editing or censoring”) and  *[redactor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redactor#Noun)* (“A person who redacts”).  I think of redaction as occurring either post-publication (*eg* copies of a book or newspaper might have pages or articles removed) or in a document-release process (*eg* a letter or article may be reviewed and parts of it deleted before delivery or release) rather than before publication.  However, the two senses  of redaction quoted above seem to allow changes before publication, although the etymology of *[redact](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=redact)* (essentially, “back action”) militates against that interpretation.

Comment: These may be the words;To be precise, I am looking for the word which I read long ago on BBC website regarding some politics issue. Unfortunately, I didn't take a note of it. Could you help me in the way my search of the word on the web should be directed (how to find out a word from (bottom-top)its meaning to the word-may sound silly ;p)

Comment: @Manoj, see links in following: [example1](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/12973/11433); [example2](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/8034/11433); [example3](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1486/11433). Particularly [onelook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=approval).   Also see [dico](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=approval&send=Look+it+up)

Comment: Thank a lot. onelook.com is awesome. I found the word- it's "redact." :) :). Does my question, in anyway, lead to the answer(redact) from your point of view? else how could I re-frame the question in order to get the correct answer?

Comment: Mainly by saying *after* the article is published, instead of *before*, in the question :)  (See edit)  But in general, additional context in question, or precise and distinct examples, will aid people in guessing the word.

Answer (score 2):

The term **[vetting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vetting)** is often used

> to subject to usually expert appraisal or correction: *vet a manuscript*

The phrase **[sign off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sign+off)** is also used

> to approve or acknowledge something by or as if by a signature: *sign off on a memo*

Answer (score 0):

"pre-publication review" or "pre-publication approval"?