# Idiom thesaurus?

Tags: meaning, idioms, resources, online-resources

Can you recommend some searchable resource that maps given expression onto idioms meaning that thing?

There are quite a few dictionaries that contain a list of idioms containing a given word which is useful if you encounter the given idiom and want to know its meaning. If I search for "horse", I will get "get on a high horse", "horse sense" or "dark horse" or "a horse of different color".

What I need is a writer's resource, a thesaurus, where I know the basic meaning and I can give its straight, direct wording, but the situation really calls upon using some smart idiom in that place. Say, I want to know idioms for "different", and get "a horse of different color", "another cup of tea" and "a whole new ball game".

Comment: There are lots of helpful links in the answer to this ELU question: [What are your favorite English language tools?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1482/18655) Probably my favorite site that gives lots of context for words/idioms/phrases is http://www.wordnik.com/

Comment: @JLG It seems like the "reverse dictionary" section of Wordnik does pretty much what I want, listing entries that use current entry in their definitions. Still, Wordnik isn't very rich in idioms, and too common expressions appear in countless definitions only barely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this spot, SF: http://www.visualthesaurus.com/app/view

and Rodale's "Synonym Finder" (a paper book; no online presence that I know of) is also quite good for more extensive idiomatic phrases.

Comment: The visual thesaurus seems to only offer word synonyms and phrasal verbs, no idiomatic phrases.

Answer (score 0):

*The Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms* is the only resource that I know of. It has more than 6000 entries, accompanied by etymological information related to the idiom. It has a searchable app on the AppStore for [iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/english-idioms-oxford-dictionary/id455355541?mt=8) users. It also comes in hard copy [book format](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019954378X) if you don't own these devices.

Both of these options are a bit pricy. But the app version, if you own an iOS device is I think worth the price.

[image][image]

Comment: What the screenshot shows seems exactly like the common idiom lists I mentioned, bundling idioms by a common word occurring inside them, and not by their meaning - multiple idioms of various unrelated meanings containing the word "above" instead of giving a list of idioms with a common meaning ("above yourself", "stuck up", "nose up in the air")