# Is there such a thing as an idiom thesaurus that delivers synonymous phrases?

Tags: phrases, idioms, synonyms, resources, online-resources

Is there a resource that anyone knows of that is a searchable idiom list that can provide synonymous phrases for idioms. For example, I saw on your site:  step-by-step, day-by-day, inch-by-inch, and bit-by-bit.  When I Google a phrase, I most often get a one-word synonym, but I'm looking specifically for additional synonymous phrases instead. In other words, is there something that can find synonyms and antonyms for idioms that are also idioms? If so, please provide a link to it. Thanks!

Comment: Such questions are generally considered off-topic on this site. Also, a dupe of [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84436/idiom-thesaurus) which has been closed.

Answer (score 3):

Oxford University Press has an [idioms Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194317234). You can also check out its [collocations dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194325385), which has idiomatic phrases for many words.

Answer (score 2):

The [Roget's thesaurus](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-b_mrr_1?rh=k%3arogets%20thesaurus,n:283155,p_n_feature_browse-bin:2656020011&bbn=283155&keywords=rogets%20thesaurus&ie=UTF8&qid=1354573000&rnid=618072011) contains a surprising number of idioms. I would consider checking it out at a local book store just to see if it will meet your needs.

Other than this, when I did a search at Amazon for "[idiom thesaurus](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=idiom%20thesaurus&rh=n:283155,k%3aidiom%20thesaurus)", I did get a few hits. I don't know anything about the books, but you can read the reviews and see what people are saying about those listed.

Comment: Anyone have an idea where else I can post this question?  Evidently this is the wrong forum since they've closed it off.

Comment: Note the comment on the question itself, with a link to another question that is a "dupe" (duplicate) of this question.