# A good and exhaustive book for English grammar

Tags: grammar, resources, books

Before marking this post duplicate or voting to get it closed (the reason for which I simply don't get just because it is a grammar forum after all! If I am seeking recommendation for a book that means I will be coming back someday to the same site for my doubts also provided I get a not so harsh reply!), please read this and help this MBA aspirant.

A little about myself and my research so far. I am a very critical reader of English Grammar and the kind of person who aims at perfection. 
Currently, I am keen on taking on English grammar again after a certain gap. Well, I am aiming for MBA, so preparing for entrance exams for the same. 
I bought the religiously followed **Wren and Martin** and started studying it chapter by chapter. I was surprised when I read the pronouns chapter. I studied all the rules given and then started practising but it came as surprise when I found when many of the attempted questions were wrong. The reason simply being the rules for those specific sentences were not given.

For example:

> We scored as many goals as they/them?

According to me, the answer should be *they*, but it's *them* according to the solution manual. Worse still, the solution manual offers no explanation for this.

So after a chat with my teachers I was suggested to follow the blogs of grammarians and look for any rules for the sentences that have contradictory answers!

I did so and was clarified by [this](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/pronoun.asp) post of pronouns, Rule 5.

Then I saw a book by the same author. I was momentarily happy. It was Momentarily because the reviews on Amazon were too bad about this book. After reading a couple of forums about the book I found a common statement saying that *no grammar book is exhaustive.*

So, it's okay for me to have more than one. And my simple question is what will be a good and *almost exhaustive* (if not fully exhaustive) book of English grammar to help get through the subtle usages of English in my management entrances  which is crisp and to the point and yet covers all important rules and syntax, and most importantly having *practice tests* at the end *with solutions* and explanations?

Comment: You may find *[What good reference works on English are available online?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573)* and *[What are your favorite English language tools?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482)* helpful. Please note that this is not a "grammar forum"; it is [not a forum](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) at all. Our sister site at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be a good resource for you as well.

Comment: @choster Sir,please ignore my specific terms like forum as i said earlier. I don't know then what i should call it. But anyway the comment you posted only suggests an exhaustive set of english resources . I am not looking for dictionaries and good reads but just GRAMMAR books. And meanwhile i am posting to the ell.stackexchange.com too if you don't like it here !

Comment: You're right, finding _exhaustive_ sources is tough. I think good starts are [Garner's Modern American Usage](http://amzn.com/0195382757), [English Grammar in Use](http://amzn.com/0521186471), and maybe a style guide, like the [Chicago Manual of Style](http://amzn.com/0226104206). If those seem useful I can post more as an answer. Best of luck on your MBA.

Comment: One of the reasons Stack Exchange doesn't like this sort of recommendation question is that they date easily. What might be a good answer today could be rendered obsolete tomorrow if the recommended book goes out of print, or a better one is published. It's also hugely subjective. [Admittedly, @Reg's CGEL is unlikely to go out of print, or be bettered!]

Comment: @jboneca  Your second link of "English grammar in Use" is going to be my  saviour in the sense that it looks exhaustive. The manuals of style are not yet my cup of tea . Maybe at some later stage if i get lucky enough to write my own articles :P. If you have read please draw upon more about this book , if it contains practice tests with explanations and not just blunt solutions .And you are free to post some other good works and yes this time i am aiming for a secondary book ( less exhaustive) to read along with the above mentioned book. Cheers !

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree sir. But moderators or the top-notch grammarians can always correct such misleading suggestions for outdated works . Right ?

Comment: Well, actually, no, because it means keeping tabs on the recommendations in the first place. SE does not lend itself to tracking a moving target.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a subject [listed as on-topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and every potential answer is [equally valid](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: There is an interesting & short & well organized grammar book called `<Grammar for English Language Teachers>`, it's very good & easy to read.

Comment: That this question is closed is very ironic, in particular, the reason "off-topic"  or "opinion-based".  When you say a question is opinion-based, what do you mean? The answers to that question are more than one or two or three...? I just come from the question "Should I always use a comma after “e.g.” or “i.e.”?" I don't get definite answer, there are two opinions from my view, so why don't you vote to close that disturbing question? By the way, why does not people close the  Philosophy in stackexchange?

Answer (score 11):

Get yourself a copy of [The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/). It's very expensive. It's very thick. It's also excellent. And if it's not exhaustive, then *exhaustive* has no meaning. It will be quick to point out that your "Rule 5 on this post of pronouns" is oversimplified to put it mildly, and stuff and nonsense to be frank, and it will tell you why.

If you can't afford CGEL to look up a particular intricacy of the language, you can always just ask about it here. That's what this site is *all about*, you know.

Comment: Yes sir, it's too expensive and i will definitely look forward to ask any such nuances and subtleties here only . But was just looking for a quick reference for such common and nascent questions of mine.

Comment: But please bear in mind whether you will require a guide for British or American English - or any other variant. I don't have good examples for you at present, but this can make a huge difference as to whether your usage is considered correct/natural/consistent.