# Which organizations responsible for formalizing English Language (British and American)

Tags: american-english, british-english

I need this information to make my own English language site, but I do not want to use copy-paste from other sites or books. I need to find the source of information to make a correct content.

If there are no such organizations can you give me a most competent source of such information?

Comment: This is a strange request. If you want to start your own English language site, then you will have to scour the internet and/or invest in good books to guide you. There is no *English Academy* to regulate the language. You might find [this question on resources](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/) helpful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about English language and usage but a request for resources.

Comment: What is "correct" in the context of the English language? Unlike some European languages, there's no standards body for the English language that I know of. Stop looking. What you need is a person or an organization knowledgeable enough and preferably an acknowledged authority.

Comment: May be migrated to meta.

Comment: So basically there is no well-known organization who formalize the rules. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to maintain separate versions for British and American, I recommend you find a native British English speaker and a native American English speaker to proofread and edit your content,  If your audience is primarily British, or if you have no access to a native speaker of American English, just do the British version; if the contrary, just do an American version. You will not learn enough of the rules from any one "source"; just do your best, then have it edited. There are too many subtle differences between American and British English. If you can set your spell/grammar checker to use a British or American English dictionary, that might be a good start, at least for spelling. But it won't fix all your usage and syntax, let alone ensure proper use of idiomatic expressions.