# what does it mean to talk with an injured sniff

Tags: meaning

What does this expression mean when one says something with an injured sniff?
can be found in chapter one of "Little Women".

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) are off-topic. Have you tried looking the words up in a dictionary? What remains unclear to you after doing so?

Comment: Nice question. I think that this: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), might be the site for you though! :)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source material:

> “Christmas won’t be Christmas without any presents,” grumbled Jo,
>   lying on the rug,
>
> “It’s so dreadful to be poor!” sighed Meg, looking down at her old
>   dress.
>
> "I don’t think it’s fair for some girls to have plenty of pretty
>   things, and other girls nothing at all,” added little Amy, with an
>   injured sniff.

It's apparent in this context that Amy's words were said with a "sniff" -- a very slight inhalation through the nose.  And the narrator adds the adjective "injured" to indicate not that the "sniff" was somehow injured, but that "little Amy" was speaking in a tone of voice that suggested her own emotional injury (and that likely the sniff was the result of this perceived "injury", not an impending cold).