# Memorable or Recall or what

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I used in a sentence:   your most memorable dream.
I meant it as the dream I thought of first.
It was interpreted as the dream which is remembered with the most detail.

Memorable means, "worth remembering" or "easily remembered." I looked at recall and it means, "to bring back from memory." I didn't think that fit.

Can I use memorable in my sentence and have it mean "thought of first" or is there a better word? What word would I use to state "remembered with the most detail."

Comment: The interpreter of your statement applied the more obvious meaning of the phrase *your most memorable dream*.

Comment: IF I really wanted to know which dream a person thinks of first, I might ask, "What's the first dream that comes to mind?" I would also interpret "most memorable" as the one I remember the most about.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to make the distinction; if you remember something first when asked about it, it must be the most memorable, and vice versa.

Comment: "best remembered" dream.

Comment: A cursory google-search resulted in: **memorable** *adjective*: **worth remembering or easily remembered, especially because of being special or unusual.** BTW, hello & welcome to ELU! Thank you for participating. There’s a lot to learn about the site, like how to ask a good question or provide a good answer. I’d recommend you start by taking the [**tour**](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour). And check out the resource links here [resource links](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools). Have fun, and we’ll see you around.

Answer (score 1):

1. [vivid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vivid): of a picture, memory, dream, etc.  seeming like real life because it is very clear, bright, or detailed. Example; " a vivid dream."
2. [obvious](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/obvious) is what we think of first.Example: " it is obvious why you remembered this dream first" or "it's an obvious dream."

Comment: I'd think a "vivid dream" is a dream in which you feel like you're in real like.