# which is more correct? "of my own age" or "of my same age"

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs, parts-of-speech

I really faced that problem a lot. So, I want to end these frustrations and make it clear for me in order to improve my English

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person "of my own age" sounds more natural to me as a native American English speaker living in northern California.

Comment: You are very welcome, Mahmoud.

Comment: Mr.Mark,
My mother tongue is not English. actually,it is Arabic, and I want good in English by improving the 4 skills but I don't know how?. I will take the TOEFL IBT exam. and I want to get a 100+ score. So, Can you help me by giving me some tips, sites, things to work on In order to improve my English to get my desired score. 
Thanks in advance Mr.mark

Comment: Mr. Nasrallah, excellent! My only suggestion is to read as much as you  can, not just books on learning English but also magazines and books on general subjects to familiarize yourself with current English usage. English is a very difficult language to learn, and I respect you very much for doing so.

Comment: @MahmoudAkramNasrallah Informative resource requests are technically off topic here but we do have a few topics listing them like [What are Your favorite English Language Tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) and [What Good Reference Works are Available in English?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) (on the meta-site) you may want to examine. The sister community [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also be worth seeing.

Comment: Thank you, @Tonepoet. I will bookmark those references for myself as well.

Comment: Thanks for helping
I really appreciate it
Thanks for helping @Tonepoet and Mr.Mark

Answer (score -1):

Mr. Nasrallah, Mr. Hubbard: I respect and applaud the both of you for your pursuit of knowledge and for your efforts to share the same with others...in the same spirit, I wish to expound upon Mr. Hubbard's reply, if I may? I've had several Arabic friends who benefited from formal English Language Instruction and printed media; yet, benefited immensely by just exercising verbal skills with fellow students, with English-speaking friends and acquaintances, with employees of businesses you frequent...take advantage of every opportunity! I'll conclude by extending my congratulations to you, Mr. Nasrallah!

Mr. Hubbard, thank you ever so much! I'm new to this site...please excuse me for the chit-chat; I felt this reply may be helpful and so, it is well-intended. I promise to control myself better in the future. Thank you for your most instructive replies to these queries and thanks also to the informative replies of these readers and contributors. J.D.