# Idiom for "intellectually malnourished"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

Titular phrase serves the meaning well enough, just that I've got the nagging feeling of forgetting a more common, less conspicuous one. Intellectual deprivation could ring derogatory. Intellectual starvation... a bit strong.

Comment: Small-minded, provincial perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

scatterbrained, numskulled  as in slow thinker, someone lacking intellectuality

Foboko describes scatterbrained as :

https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/scatterbrained

nescient as in ignorant

https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/nescient

Comment: Hi Subrat Bavarian Bastola, welcome to ELU. This looks to be the start of a good answer. Would it be possible to provide references with excerpts as per site policy?

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned it's an idiom and not derogatory, though I should clarify it also starts with 'intellectual[ly]'.

Comment: I'd preferred one of https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available but it serves. Maybe you can propose this site as well?

Comment: Similar: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools