# Circle "with radius" vs. "of radius"

Tags: prepositions

Are both of there correct?

1. Circle with radius r = 1 cm.
2. Circle of radius r = 1 cm.

I do not want to use other sentences such as "Radius of a circle is r = 1 cm."

Comment: I do not really understand how this is opinion-based. I asked whether these are correct and I was hoping English language had rules which can decide this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can say both but "circle *of* radius r=" is much preferred, as this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circle+of+radius%2Ccircle+with+radius&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircle%20of%20radius%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircle%20with%20radius%3B%2Cc0) shows.

This  preference persists when the head of the prepositional complement is followed by the mathematical symbol "=": [ngram "="](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=circle+of+radius+r+%3D%2Ccircle+with+radius+r+%3D&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccircle%20of%20radius%20r%20%3D%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircle%20with%20radius%20r%20%3D%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccircle%20of%20radius%20r%20%3D%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccircle%20with%20radius%20r%20%3D%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I would have said either  “circle with radius r=3” or “circle of radius 3” but not “circle of radius r=3”

Comment: @Jim I made an addition to my answer.

Comment: Has *anyone* any idea of the reason of at least 4 negative votes on this answer?

Comment: I've added a DV. I've resisted in the last couple of questions I've looked at, but questions lacking basic research (eg easy Google ngram searches), where solutions are reasonably based on them, should be close-voted and not answered.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Should learners at the beginning of their studies know about the use of ngrams or even what prepositions are more likely than others? Is the use of Google ngrams made clear to all?

Comment: Of course not. But ELU is expressly aimed at people who are beyond the basics. Please take the 'tour' and look at relevant discussions at the Help Center. Why do you think there is the close-vote reason that points out lack of basic research? Google ngrams is mentioned in the list of basic resources research from which should, where relevant, be included with a question. This will eliminate basic questions, and help enquirers become more independent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I went through a few links stemming from "Help", but could not find any mention of Google; if you have an easy access to a Stack-Exchange link leading to information about Google, but only if you don't have to do any research, as I don't want to take up your time for that, would you please make it known to me?

Comment: [What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) is the master list. [What are your favorite English language tools?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/what-are-your-favorite-english-language-tools) is perhaps more easily formatted. It includes both raw Google searches, and Google ngrams. // There's even been a question investigating the accuracy of ngrams and of their interpretations. // I'm not sure...

Comment: why 'this is merely a matter of opinion' is the CV-reason for the question here; I'd cite lack of reasonable research.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth On the basis of the links you indicate (an obscure meta question (that nobody knows of) and an ELU question (closed, off topic, on top of that)), I can see that the new enquirers have absolutely no information about the usual means of getting the basic facts; it seems that the various sources should be explicitly mentioned in the Help section, as well as the way to use them; otherwise I don't see how can newcomers   be reproached with not using them in the first stage of their research.

Comment: Raise this on Meta. Many people here know the rules, and the _lacking basic research_ CV blurb is often seen, so contributors with over say 5000 rep should know better than to answer off-topic questions. ELU is self policing, but the rules are discussed on ELU.Meta. // I get the flak, because I usually explain DVs amd CVs.