# Is there a more common phrase that means "preponed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, neologisms

I was aware of this and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-prepone-being-used-outside-india) stackexchange post discuss the same. There is no *prepone* in English. Ok, then how do I say *Our meeting is preponed* in correct way? What is the correct word/phrase for *prepone*?

Comment: Great observation — it is strange that this word hasn't spread into common use.

Comment: Just use "prepone" whenever the rest of the context makes the meaning clear; it's a great word and we can make it eventually catch on. ;-)

Comment: I usually do not use the word outside of India, or if i have colleagues who are not Indian in the meeting. So most of the time i use 'rescheduled or postponed'. But preponed is a good word it should get added into English dictionaries.

Comment: Oxford's added prepone: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prepone

Comment: For a germanic verb, in Norwegian, we say _framskynde_ – literally _forwardhurry_.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Our meeting has been brought forward.
>
> Our meeting has been rescheduled for an earlier time.

I wouldn't worry too much. English is my first language and I liked the word when I first heard it.

Unlike other apparent malapropisms (or eggcorns) this word is succinct, clear in meaning, and it fills a hole.

Unless I've misunderestimated the question?

Comment: I'd prefer "rescheduled" over "brought forward". I occasionally find spatial metaphors for time somewhat confusing ("brought forward" = earlier, "going forward" = in future, "advanced" = brought earlier, but "advanced a pawn" = pushed it further away), and I may not be alone.

Comment: you used one of my favorite words: "misunderestimated"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - you are definitely not alone. I find "move up a meeting by an hour" very confusing. Perhaps the spatial metaphor is an Americanism?

Comment: Can we use the phrase "The meeting has been advanced". I heard a person using this instead of "prepone"

Comment: I don't think it's logical to say "brought forward." I always strive to be logical when I speak, for example by saying, "No, it was," when somebody asks me, "Wasn't that fun?" so as a matter of principle, I don't want to say "brought forward." It is more logical to say "brought backward," but, in order to avoid this (avoiding grammatical problems is usually better than solving them), I think Jonik's answer is better: "Our meeting has been moved to an earlier time/[day]."

Comment: Related: ["forward" is sometimes used to mean sooner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540904).

Answer (score 20):

Just on a whim I checked the dictionary, and it turns out that [*prepone* is in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prepone)!  I might personally still avoid it just because many people might be confused by it (or at least take a moment to parse it), but technically it is a perfectly [cromulent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cromulent) word.

I then checked the OED and found that this word was coined in 1913.  Here is the quote, which comes from the New York Times:

> For the benefit mainly of the legal profession in this age of hurry and bustle may I be permitted to coin the word ‘prepone’ as a needed rival of that much revered and oft-invoked standby, ‘postpone’.

Comment: The _Corpus of Contemporary American English_ reports _prepone_ just once, in the sentence _In India, people created the word "prepone" as the obvious opposite of postpone._

Comment: Still, it doesn't seem to be in most (or at least many) dictionaries yet (I just checked NOAD, New Webster's, and an English-Finnish dictionary by WSOY). But I guess it'll make its way into more and more, as most people (including [myself](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/use-of-myself-in-business-speak)) seem to like it. :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that, Jonik.  And since it has been floating around in the fringes for about a hundred years and hasn't really taken hold, who knows if it ever will.

Comment: No surprise at all.  **Pre** comes from the Latin preposition prae (“before”), as **Post** comes from Latin post (“after, behind”).

Answer (score 7):

I asked to a friend of mine, born and raised on Long Island (and still living there). She told me she would say a sentence similar to the following one.

> Our meeting has been moved up.

Comment: No; I'd interpret "anticipated" in this context to mean "expected".

Comment: Do you mean that _come or take place before_ means _expected_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No, I mean that the definition of "anticipated" in your original answer doesn't match my understanding of the word.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: I got it; the meaning of _anticipated_ in the context is not the one I was giving to the word. I corrected my answer after I asked to a person who speaks American English as first language what she would say (her job was to make meetings; I trust she shows how to say that a meeting has been rescheduled to an earlier time `:-)`).

Comment: in the contexts in which I tend to operate, "moved up" means to be later (ie, it is synonymous with "pushed"), whereas "moved back" means that it is happening closer to "now".

Comment: @warren: That's the opposite of my experience. "Moved ahead" also means "moved up", by the way.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Do you mean that in your experience, you use _moved up_ when the meeting has been scheduled for a earlier date/time? The answer I gave is the answer that I got; it seems more logical to me that _moved up_ is used to mean the meetings has been moved to an earlier time, maybe because I interpret it as _moved up on the calendar_.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson .. maybe it's a regional or cultural thing?

Comment: @warren: I don't know. I can only say that the person I asked to lives on Long Island (NY).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, I understand "moved up" and "moved ahead" to mean sooner and "moved back" to mean later (than the original time).

Comment: This is the best answer since it's what people actually say in the situation.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what [Ed Guiness said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/then-how-do-i-say-it-our-meeting-is-preponed/2247#2247),

> Our meeting has been moved to this afternoon.

<sup>(Assuming, obviously, that the original time was later than *this afternoon*, e.g. tomorrow morning.)</sup>

Or if you want to give emphasis to the "preponing":

> Our meeting has been moved to an earlier time/date: [...]

But go ahead and use "prepone" if you have reason to believe that the people you are addressing are familiar with the term (or at least wouldn't object to using it). :-)

Comment: The first sentence doesn't mean that the meeting as scheduled for an earlier time; if the meeting was first scheduled for the morning, saying that it has been moved to this afternoon would mean that the meeting has been postponed.

Comment: Oh, rly? :-P The assumption that the original time was later than "this afteroon" was implicit, but (I thought) obvious enough in this context.