# "...to my friend, my sister and me"

Tags: phrases, conjunctions

Which is the best way to phrase this sentence?

"That made a world of difference to my friend, my sister and me"

"That made a world of difference to my friend, my sister and to me"

"That made a world of difference to my friend, my sister and myself"

Comment: Hi Ranthi! Your question has some overlap with the following questions; take a look and see if the answers there help any: [Use of “myself” in business-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2269), [When is it correct to use “yourself” and “myself” (versus “you” and “me”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176)

Answer (score 0):

Both the first and second phrases are perfectly acceptable, though the first is probably the better form since it doesn't have the unnecessary repetition of "to" that the second phrase does.

The third phrase is incorrect, because it uses an object pronoun that is not supposed to be used in that situation. The word "myself" is a **reflexive object pronoun**. Reflexive object pronouns are used when the object of the sentence is the same person or thing as the subject of the sentence.

Examples: I washed myself. They helped themselves. You hurt yourself. He knows himself. etc..

In your phrases, the subject is "that" (which would of course be referring to something already known from context). Thus, you can't use "myself".