# How to say: "I will try to move it to an earlier time" or what is the opposite of "delay"

Tags: word-choice

I have a meeting that I think should be moved to an earlier time. What is the best way to say it?

E.g. if I wanted to move it to a later time, I can use the word "delay":

> "I would like to delay the meeting"

How do I say the oposite?

> "I would like to *_*_ the meeting" (to
>   advance? to precede? none of them
>   sound right)

Comment: In India, you can *prepone* meetings. Outside of India, that would probably get you some strange looks.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/how-do-i-say-our-meeting-is-preponed and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-prepone-being-used-outside-india

Comment: I think the most common phrase is "move the meeting up", right?

Comment: I'd rather use to _postpone_ a meeting instead of _delaying_ it. It sounds more neutral.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about "I would like to bring the meeting forward to...". This is based on [an accepted antonym of delay](http://encarta.msn.com/thesaurus_561570679/delay.html) "bring forward".

Comment: +1, since this would have been my answer too!

Comment: English is a great language, but if moving something forward in time is delaying, why just "moving it forward" is the opposite? But I can't argue with facts, I assume native speakers won't be confused when I'll tell them to move the meeting forward, however non native speakers might be, as I would have with the axis of time in their mind :)

Comment: @Ehrann I see your point. Perhaps if you think of the timeline as a physical distance. I push something back to make it be further away, I pull something forward to make it closer.

Answer (score 12):

***Advance*** fits the bill all right:

> [ trans. ] cause (an event) to occur at an earlier date than planned: *I advanced the date of the meeting by several weeks.*

Comment: Can you add link and attribution, please?

Answer (score 3):

My few cents: In actual practice I would probably just say or write:

> "Can we move our meeting on April 23rd
>   on 7 p.m. up to 5 p.m.? I'm unable to
>   make it at 7 p.m." or "Can we move our
>   meeting on April 23rd from 7 p.m. to 5
>   p.m.?"

If this was a much higher boss (or one that required a lot of deference) I would write:

> Would it be
>   convenient for you to move/reschedule
>   our meeting on April 23rd from 7 p.m.
>   to 5 p.m.? I am unable to make a 7
>   p.m. appointment on that date.

To reschedule for an earlier time (or "moving the meeting up) brings up the possibility of changing the date as well as the time, in my mind.

Comment: In my mind, "move it to an earlier time" doesn't require that it occur on the same day.

Answer (score 2):

> Expedite.
>   verb (used with object), expedited, expediting.
>   1.
>   to speed up the progress of; hasten:

Comment: you could just give an example sentence.

Comment: Yes, but that wouldn't express my irritation at the ridiculous rule. :)

Comment: see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/836/exception-to-30-character-minimum-for-answers/837#837

Comment: @Martha, I like the link to definition idea.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer has got to be [prepone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/how-do-i-say-our-meeting-is-preponed)

> I would like to prepone the meeting

or

> The meeting has been preponed

Comment: Except that "prepone" is not a real English word, at least not outside India.

Comment: But how words were added to English? isn't Language human invented after all? Just like prepend is not "real" english but one day it will... isn't it?

Comment: ELU deals with standard usage at the time of answering.

Answer (score 1):

> I would prefer to have the meeting a little earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Simple English works fine

just say "I am moving the meeting time from .... to....
or       " the meeting time have been change to instead of

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

We typically say "push out" dates to mean a delay in date or time and we "pull in" dates to mean advance or "prepone" a meeting. "prepone" is meaningless in English outside of India."push out" and "pull in" are accepted terms when speaking to schedulers who use any tool that creates Gantt Charts.The tool automatically shows an item being pushed out to the right or pulled in to the left if you change the due dates.

Answer (score 0):

Someone told me that one can also say

> I would like to move the meeting up a
>   little

(but I don't know if it's correct English)

Comment: I would prefer to have the meeting a little earlier.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great, I was just looking for the exact mirror of "I would like/prefer to delay the meeting" but your suggestion sounds better. But please put it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although, prepone is quite commonly used in India, it is rarely done so outside.

With Indian background, I was taught 'Advance a meeting" i.e. schedule a meeting earlier than the original time/date slot is the correct usage and was discouraged the use of 'prepone'.

However, I think prepone (before/earlier + put = Put it before/earlier) is self explanatory, rhymes with postpone (after + put = put it later) and the words (pre and Post) are well recognised antonym prefixes. It is about time, it (prepone) becomes part of the global English lexicon. Importantly, it is crisp and concise.

Every other iterations/solutions are relatively cumbersome.