# Antonym of Postpone

Tags: antonyms

what is the antonym of postpone. I have seen the usage of "prepone" at many places. If that is correct, the is the post used in postpone a prefix ?

Comment: I think you’ll find that [*prepone* is limited to the Indian subcontinent](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/808/2085), and not even recognized elsewhere.

Comment: Please search the site before posting. It actually gets you the answer you're looking for faster.

Answer (score 2):

*Bring forward* comes to mind -

[prepone does exist it seems](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepone)

Other antonyms

- advance
- expedite
- hasten

[Etymology from etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=postpone)

> c.1500, from Latin postponere "put after; esteem less; neglect; postpone," from post "after" (see post-) + ponere "put, place" (see position (n.)). Related: Postponed; postponing.

Comment: Also, I would add _accelerate_ to your list as possible option.