# Does the word prepone exist?

Tags: antonyms

I always thought that the opposite of postpone is prepone(also remember my english teacher telling me this). Today I realised that the word prepone does not exist in the dictionary. So is it used informally or does it exist?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-prepone-being-used-outside-india

Comment: What do you mean, "does not exist in the dictionary"? What is "the dictionary"? I can name two dozen off the top of my head. Of which [at least seven do have the word](http://www.onelook.com/?w=prepone&ls=a).

Comment: @Reg: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/265231?rskey=UjgTbu&result=2#eid) does at least include the caveat *In later use, most frequent in Indian English.*

Comment: "Prepone" would only get you dumb looks in most of the US.

Comment: @Hot Licks: "Dumb looks" as in *I must be dumb - I've no idea what you mean by that*, or *I know what you mean, but you must be dumb for using such a "non-word"*? I'd probably have been in the latter category until discovering that the word is actually common in IE, but I think the *meaning* should normally be obvious from context even if you suppose the speaker just made it up on the spot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Dumb look" as in "Are you speaking French or what?"